# OData service data binding

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I have a hard time with displaying data from OData model.

Here is the model declaration:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("northwind/V2/(S(ql0iexfh2tyudc5p4qhx5gdf))/OData/OData.svc");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "odata");
```

I have a destination for Northwind OData service with path "/northwind".

Here is my list declarations:

```
var oResultsList = new sap.m.List(); 
var oListTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    path: "odata>/Categories",
    title: "{odata>name}"
});
oResultsList.bindAggregation("items", "/", oListTemplate);
```

But I get empty list.

If I'm correct, I have a connection to the service, because I can get and see the metadata object of this service.

Where my problem is hiding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding seems to be erroneous, e.g. the property should be CategoryName and the item aggregation needs to be bound against the entity set.

```
var oListTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    description: "{odata>Description}",
    title: "{odata>CategoryName}"
});
oResultsList.bindAggregation("items", "odata>/Categories", oListTemplate);
```

Comment: I suppose adding `path` to the `oListTemplate` and not to the `.bindAggregation()` was my mistake. Now it works, thank you.